# Use FFmpeg (or sox) to reduce stereo

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, sox

The [ffmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation) has this method to mix stereo to stereo:

[image]

`ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -af "pan=stereo|c0<c0+c1|c1<c0+c1" output.ogg`

How could I do this but reduce the volume of the right part mixed into the left and the left part mixed into the right (diagonal arrows) by 60%, while leaving the volume of both channels as is (downward arrows)?

(If this could be done with sox, it be great too.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i input -af "pan=stereo|c0<c0+0.6*c1|c1<0.6*c0+c1" output
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i input -af "pan=stereo|FL<FL+0.6*FR|FR<0.6*FL+FR" output
```

Replace `<` with `=` if you don't want pan to normalize the combined gain to 1 for clipping avoidance.

See [pan filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan).